# netsuite scriptable cart - adding to cart validation on multi add

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Not sure if this is the site to ask a netsuite question on, but it is programming, so i think so.

I am working on writing a scriptable cart script in netsuite. It currently does (or is suppose to do) 2 things, it won't let you add a specific item to the cart and it won't let you add something that is already in the cart to the cart. Here is the script:

```
function customValidateLine(type)
{

if (type != 'item')
{
    return true;
}


var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','item');

if (itemId == "302"){
        return false;
}

var qty = parseInt(nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity'));
if (qty > 1){
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Currently the qty part of script works. It returns an error saying line validation failed. Item 302 is still allowed to be added to the cart.

Please note that I am using multi to add multiple items to the cart in one form submit.

```
<input type="hidden" name="multi" value="302,1;xxx,1;etc">
```

Questions:

1. Why can I still add item 302 to the cart? It is being passed in with:
2. When I catch the qty, how can I get it to just fail silently instead of throwing an error?
3. Is there a good way to debug these scripts?

Thanks

Comment: The Netsuite help suggests Firebug to debug the scriptable cart.  Presumably the Chrome developer tools would work as well.

Comment: Right. I forgot to mention that this is an external shopping cart, so the firebug debugging won't work like it would in an internal shopping cart.